# Map functions over array with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way in Postgres to apply a function over a results of an array (or any sort of collection)?

For example if I have a function `create function add1...` that increments a number by one, is there any way to do something like:

```
select map add1 array[1,5,8...];
```

and getting back

```
array [2,6,9...]
```

?

I am not sure if it has any sense over a `select` as it can map a function on the single result directly:

```
select add1(x) from X;
```

Also, is there any concept of laziness here? All the functions will be 'strictly' applied?

Comment: Only one what I could to imagine: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c179acbdbc2f0a52f0d5f81a9a9266c7

Comment: @Abelisto can't you rework that to use oids instead `map(regprocedure, anyarray, out anyarray)`

Comment: @EvanCarroll It was my second attempt, just after the `regproc`, but it caused the ugly calling syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you are merely looking to increment each element of an input array, this simple function is one method of doing it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add1 (int[]) RETURNS int[] AS
$func$
DECLARE
    e       int;
    new_arr int[] := '{}';
BEGIN
    FOREACH e IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
        e := e + 1;
        new_arr := new_arr || e;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN new_arr;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;

SELECT add1(array[1,5,8,15]::int[]);
    add1
------------
 {2,6,9,16}
```

Or queried from your table

```
select id, array_col, add1(array_col) from yourtable;
 id |      arr      |     add1
----+---------------+---------------
  1 | {1,3,6,9}     | {2,4,7,10}
  2 | {10,20,30,40} | {11,21,31,41}
```

Plain SQL version of the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add1(int[]) RETURNS int[] AS
$func$
    SELECT array_agg(vals)
    FROM (select unnest($1) + 1 as vals) AS x;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Comment: I would recommend to always use STABLE for function for do not change data in db - for  10,000 calls it 92ms instead 118ms

Comment: Good point. STABLE has been added - which got me wondering if a plain SQL version wouldn't work as well. I've added both, though the original pl/pgsql version tested a bit faster than the SQL version for me.